# calculate the difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, calendar

I trying to calculate the difference between two dates, I wrote java script function and it works fine but the problem is that it deals with days as month and vise versa.

for example:
if the first date is 2/7/2013 and the second date is 3/7/2013 it 
gives me the result 30 days instead of 1 day.

here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
}
});
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="" name="date">

<label for="from"> Start Date : </label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="start" />
<br/>
<label for="to">   End Date : </label>
<input type="text"  id="to"  name="end"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="reserve"    onclick="setDifference(this.form);"/></p>

<input type="hidden" name="result"  />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

function setDifference(frm) {
var dtElem1 = frm.elements['start'];
var dtElem2 = frm.elements['end'];
var resultElem = frm.elements['result'];

if(!dtElem1 || !dtElem2 || !resultElem) {
return;
}

var x = dtElem1.value;
var y = dtElem2.value;
var arr1 = x.split('/');
var arr2 = y.split('/');


var dt1 = new Date();
dt1.setFullYear(arr1[2], arr1[1], arr1[0]);
var dt2 = new Date();
dt2.setFullYear(arr2[2], arr2[1], arr2[0]);

resultElem.value = (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
}
</script>

<?php

$from= $_POST['start'];
$to= $_POST['end'];
$result = $_POST['result']; 
?>

Check In Date : <?php echo $from; ?></label><br />
Check Out Date : <?php echo $to; ?></label><br />
Number Of days: <?php echo $result; ?></label><br />
<BR/>
```

Comment: looks like format is mm/dd/yyyy not dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

mm/dd/yyyy not dd/mm/yyyy

```
var dt1 = new Date();
dt1.setFullYear(arr1[1], arr1[2], arr1[0]);
var dt2 = new Date();
dt2.setFullYear(arr2[1], arr2[2], arr2[0]);

resultElem.value = (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
```

Comment: I tried the code and it give me this result:                      Check In Date : 07/02/2013
Check Out Date : 07/03/2013
Number Of days: 365

Comment: it supposed to be 1 day not 365

Comment: There's no need to call `.getTime()` on both `Date`s - you can just subtract `Date` objects...so `(dt2 - dt1)` would work fine